# replacing a non-virtual method in a third party class

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I need to override a method from some third party library and then inject result object to another third party library. The problem is that method is not virtual so I cannot override it. It looks like a solution to use the SwapMethodBody method but it is not implemented in Mono.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[MonoTODO]
[SecurityPermission (SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
public static void SwapMethodBody (Type cls, int methodtoken, IntPtr rgIL, int methodSize, int flags)
{
    if (methodSize <= 0 || methodSize >= 4128768) {
        throw new ArgumentException ("Data size must be > 0 and < 0x3f0000", "methodSize");
    }
    if (cls == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("cls");
    }
    if (cls is TypeBuilder && !((TypeBuilder)cls).is_created) {
        throw new NotSupportedException ("Type '" + cls + "' is not yet created.");
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException ();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what's wrong with using `new` instead of `override`? (aside from not being the best design principle)

Comment: I cannot use new. Let's say the method is in class A and third party library designed to use exactly that class. If I will inject my class with the method which is hidden by new it will actually use the original but not my.

Comment: I think this is actually a pretty good question, but i don't think i can solve this for you. I updated the title for better visibility (i think you were downvoted just because someone read the title and thought "nope, you can't override nonvirtual methods")

Comment: I have a similar problem, I can't use this functionality in Mono to patch a method! have you found the solution yet? @Radiofisik

Comment: @hiradyazdan no, I had to find some workaround solution...

Comment: I also ended up using Harmony which looks a bit overkill but works perfectly fine.